# Selecting Second Node in XML for DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, data-binding, datagrid

I am taking a XML file and binding it to a DataGrid.  I have an issue.  There are two child nodes in the XML file and I want the second node to be bound to the DataGrid.

Here is an example of the XML file:

```
<Root>

  <Header>
    <value1>0000000</value1>
    <value2>1</value2>
    <value3>100.00</value3>
  </Header>

  <Transactions>
    <Txn>
      <Login></Login>
      <UserName>Bob</User>
      <Customer>Bob Smith</Customer>
    </Txn>
  </Transactions>

</Root>
```

I want to bind the Transactions to the DataGrid.  Currently, when I bind the above XML file to the DataGrid, all I get is the Header values being populated.  I would like the code to skip the Header and just bind the Transactions.

Here is my C# code in the Default.aspx.cs file:

```
    public void LoadXML()
    {
        try
        {
            serverPath = Server.MapPath("App_Data/" + xmlFileName);
            DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();
            dsDataSet.ReadXml(serverPath);
            dgDataGrid.DataSource = dsDataSet;
            dgDataGrid.DataBind();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadXML will have loaded the xml structure into separate tables.  If you bind to dsDataSet.Tables[2] it'll show all of your transactions.

Answer (score 0):

To get both "Header" and "Transaction"

```
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0] ;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
        GridView2.DataBind();
```